# Copy Worksheet to ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to collate two worksheets (both named "deliverable") from two workbooks to a third workbook.

The file names change constantly as all three workbooks are named depending on the quarter (Q1/2/3/4).
I tried to refer to the "source" workbooks by their index numbers (2 and 3 respectively, as the "target" workbook will be opened first and it is where the macro will be run), and for .copy after I have used ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1, and 2 respectively).

Receiving

> Run-time error '9'

The error seems to be isolated to the first line of code. When I remove it the third line runs as it should.

I tried to isolate the issue by referring to workbook by name rather than index, and referring to the worksheet by index rather than "deliverable".

```
Workbooks(2).Sheets("Deliverable").Copy After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Q3 2020"
'
Workbooks(3).Sheets("Deliverable").Copy After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Q2 2020"
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to the title or edit a solution into the question itself. If an answer was posted that helped you solve the problem, you can indicate that the problem was solved by accepting that answer. If you found a solution yourself that you'd like to share, do so by writing your own answer to the question in the space provided below for that purpose. You can find more information about how the site works in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThisWorkbook` if that's where the code is running, and it's best to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`/`ActiveSheet` if you can:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook
    Workbooks(2).Sheets("Deliverable").Copy After:=.WorkSheets(1)
    .WorkSheets(2).Name = "Q3 2020"

    Workbooks(3).Sheets("Deliverable").Copy After:=.WorkSheets(2)
    .WorkSheets(3).Name = "Q2 2020"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but the problem still appears to exist. Could it be that rather than workbooks 2 and 3, I should be referring to them as 3 and 4 given I have open: 1) the workbook which the data pulls through to and where I am running the code, and 2) I suppose my personal macro workbook is technically always open? When changing the indexes to 3 and 4 the code appears to run well!

Comment: If the workbook names are consistent then using the names would be better.  Or if you're opening the workbooks using code then you can get a reference to each one at that point.

Comment: Thanks again! The workbook names aren’t constant, which has lead me to exploring this solution... currently opening workbooks manually as they are stored in Sharepoint (I’m not quite there yet in terms of my understanding of its feasibility...) but will definitely check that out.